# Программа выдаёт не то значение, которое требуется

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы

Дано задание написать программу для решения уравнения методом деления отрезка пополам. Код вроде как без ошибок, но вот беда в результате. он немного отличается от нужного. Может я где накосячил, кто может помочь?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double fun(double x) {
    double f;
    f = tan(x) - pow(tan(x),3) * x + 1 / 3 + 0.2 * pow(tan(x),5) * x;
    return f;
}
int main(){
    double x, d, c, eps;
    eps = 0.00000001;
    c = 0;
    d = 0.8;
    while (d - c > eps) {
        x = (c + d) / 2;
        if (fun(c)*fun(x) < 0){
            d = x;
        }
        else {
            c = x;
        }
    }
    cout << "c = " << c << " " << "f(c) = " << fun(c) << endl;
    cout << "d = " << d << " " << "f(d) = " << fun(d) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Промежуток, которое имеет корень уравнения : [0;0.8]
а приближенное значение уравнения : 0.3333

Но я получаю только 0.341536

Это можно считать за верное решение задачи, либо нет?

Comment: Не `1/3` - это ноль, а `1./3`.

Comment: @Harry тогда ответ получается вовсе не такой

Comment: Какая у вас функция? Может, вы ее неверно записали? Дело в том, что для вашей функции решения `f(x)==0` на указанном участке НЕТ.

Comment: @Harry tg x-( tg^3 x+1)/3+0.2tg^5 x

Comment: А вы написали tg(x) + x*(tg(x))^3 + 1/3 + 0.2x(tg(x))^5. Кстати, ваше tg^3x — это взять тангенс и возвести полученное значение в куб, или тангенс от тангенса от тангенса?

Comment: @Harry А если, допустим, так?
tan(x) - (pow(tan(x),3) * x + 1.0) / 3 + 0.2 * pow(tan(x),5) * x

Comment: @Harry tg^3x это возвести в куб

Answer (score 2):

На отрезке [-1,1] ваша функция имеет вид (конечно, если исправить ошибку целочисленного деления):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваша программа с `c = -1`, `d = 1` дает верное решение -0.312442.

**Update** после выяснения того, какое же уравнение надо решать *на самом деле*...

Если записать вашу функцию **правильно**, как

```
double fun(double x) {
    double f = tan(x);
    return -1./3 + f*(1 - f*f*(1./3-f*f/5));
}
```

то ваша программа даст верный ответ 0.333255, что соответствует графику функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А отсюда несколько моралей...

1. Задавая вопрос, надо дать *точное* задание, а не свою вольную трактовку — словами ли, в коде ли.
2. При решении задачи всегда проверяйте **применимость метода**. Вы проверили в самом начале, что `f(c)*f(d) < 0`? нет. А были обязаны. Еще надо проверить, что функция непрерывна на данном отрезке. Потому что иначе сам метод неприменим!